# How can I use layout gravity for image in ImageView inside constraintLayout?

Tags: android

I have a Constraint Layout inside which I have ImageView, Text View and another TextView all arranged vertically below one another respectively.

I populated the ImageView using a vector drawable, but its populated in center of the ImageView whereas I want it to be left aligned. I tried using layout_gravity but that doesn't work since it's inside ConstraintLayout.

Here is the code of the layout:

```
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="9"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/color_pallete"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:text="Create"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.87" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:text="ABC"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Can anyone advise me how can I achieve left aligning of image in ImageView above?

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to do this

ImageView has API to align the Image within the ImageView.
see `android:scaleType="fitStart"`

ConstraintLayout allows you to set the
AspectRatio and constraint to start_toStart="parent" if you know the image ahead of time.

```xml
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
...
```